# .scrollIntoView any element with data- tag, or using classes to section content with data- tags

Tags: javascript, html

Right now, I separate my content with a class called "section", not to be confused with the html  tag, e.g.:

```
<div class="section" data-scroll-location="top">
<nav></nav>
</div><!-- .section -->

<div class="section" data-scroll-location="content">
<p></p>
</div><!-- .section -->

<div class="section" data-scroll-location="bottom">
<footer></footer>
</div><!-- .section -->
```

Using the above method, I can easily grab each elementsByClassName('section'), and gather the data- value; however, I am not sure how to efficiently grab a data- tag without using a class, e.g.:

```
<header data-scroll-location="top"></header>

<p data-scroll-location="content"></p>

<footer data-scroll-location="bottom"></footer>
```

I could create a loop to grab every single element, right? But, would it not be a bad thing to do performance wise, or [insert con I am not aware of]?

What method would you use for a site with maybe 3-5 scroll destinations?

**EDIT:**

With the answer to my question, I was able to come up with this:

```
function jump(destination) {
    var scrollpoint = document.querySelectorAll('[data-scroll-location=' + destination + ']');
    [].forEach.call(scrollpoint, function(land) {
        land.scrollIntoView();
    });
}
```

querySelectorAll really is awesome, it will help in so many projects!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over all your elements sounds innefective, yes:)
I would use document.querySelectorAll to select your data-elements. It is supported by IE8 and up. It will give you a NodeList of the matching elements. It's not actually an Array, so forEach won't work for iterating over them, unless you use it like this:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-scroll-location]');
[].forEach.call(elems,function(elem){
    //Here you can do whatever with each element
    elem.innerHTML = 'I changed this';
    elem.style.color = 'green';    
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1239m1tz/